# Un-check checkbox with matching ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a bit of an issue I hope someone could help with, I've tried a few different ideas and haven't gotten anywhere.

I've made the script make a list of the checkbox items appear on click of each checkbox but what I want to do is when you click the 'X' on the opened list item for it to uncheck the matching input.

I've got a working CodePen here to show you what I mean:

https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/dLoOVE

Any help is appreciated and if I need to explain further then let me know :)

I've tried a few different ideas but can't get the logic of matching it up to it's corresponding input quite right.

```js
//demo example
$(function() {
    var $allProducts = $(".js-refinement-link.input-checkbox");
    var $selectedProductsListing = $(".selectedProducts");

    $allProducts.on("click", function(e) {
        $selectedProductsListing.html(
            $allProducts
                .filter(":checked")
                .map(function(index, checkbox) {
                    return (
                        '<li class="checked-items ' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        '" id="' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        '"><span>' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        "</span></li>"
                    );
                })
                .get()
                .join("") 
        );
    });
});
```

```css
.ul-reset {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.selectedProducts {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.checked-items { 
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.checked-items span {
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid tomato;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #333;
    display: flex;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.checked-items span:after {
   color: red;
    width: 12px;
    content: 'X';
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test-list ul-reset">

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product1" id="Product1"/><label for="Product1">Product 1</label>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product2" id="Product2"/><label for="Product2">Product 2</label>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product3" id="Product3"/><label for="Product3">Product 3</label>
    </li>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product4"  id="Product4"><label for="Product4">Product 4</label>
    </li>

    <ul class="selectedProducts ul-reset"></ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROPZvE

I add:

```
  //On click in each .checked-items span
  $(document).on('click','.checked-items span',function(){
      //Remove the clicked element
      $(this).parent().remove();
      //Get the html referenced to the checkbox#id
      var checkId = $(this).html();
      //Unchecked the checbox
      $('#'+checkId).prop('checked',false)
  })
```

Yes, the `:after` should be changed by a DOM element. to make it clear:

```
$(document).on('click','.checked-items span .theXElement',function(){
```

Comment: Should remove when the `X` clicked, in your example, all the span does it.

Comment: That's becouse `X` is a pseudo-element (not in DOM) imposibble to get by jQuery. He should change the way he created the `x` and make that new element the clickedReciber

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly bind events to pseudo elements and therefore the route to go here would to be either have a click event listening on the parent element (As @Roy's answer shows) but this will have an event listener on this whole span.

Your other solution would to be have a child element inside .checked-items which holds your 'X' rather than using the pseudo element (:after). This way you will be able to directly bind to the element.

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you can't access the element you created with the `::after` CSS selector, because it is not really a part of your DOM.

A solution to make your code work: replace that with a real element, like another `<span>` with a class `.after` (or what you want), and add an event listener on these tags.

```js
//demo example
$(function() {
    var $allProducts = $(".js-refinement-link.input-checkbox");
    var $selectedProductsListing = $(".selectedProducts");

    $allProducts.on("click", function(e) {
        $selectedProductsListing.html(
            $allProducts
                .filter(":checked")
                .map(function(index, checkbox) {
                    // Added a <span.after> here
                    return ('<li class="checked-items ' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        '" id="' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        '"><span>' +
                        checkbox.id +
                        '<span class="after">X</span></span></li>'
                    );
                })
                .get()
                .join("") 
        );
    });
    
    // Dynamic event listener.
    $(document).on('click', '.checked-items .after', function() {
      const chkId = `#${$(this).parents('.checked-items').first().attr('id')}`;
      
      $(chkId).prop('checked', false);
      $(this).parents('.checked-items').first().remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.ul-reset {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.selectedProducts {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.checked-items { 
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.checked-items > span:first-of-type {
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid tomato;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #333;
    display: flex;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

// Not using ::after, but .after class instead
.checked-items > span:first-of-type .after {
   color: red;
    width: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test-list ul-reset">

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product1" id="Product1"/><label for="Product1">Product 1</label>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product2" id="Product2"/><label for="Product2">Product 2</label>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product3" id="Product3"/><label for="Product3">Product 3</label>
    </li>

    <li class="m-label-inline">
        <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Product4"  id="Product4"><label for="Product4">Product 4</label>
    </li>

    <ul class="selectedProducts ul-reset"></ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions!